# javacc (ph-javacc-maven-plugin) generates java switch with case `\`

Tags: java, el, javacc, parser-generator

I'm a newly to javacc. I tried to parse an existing javacc grammar (its the [JSR341, EL 3.0 Grammar](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr341/index.html)). It generates (almost) correct java. However, the generated code contains an illegal switch statement. I'm using the ph-javacc-maven-plugin.

```
private int jjMoveStringLiteralDfa0_0(){
   switch(curChar)
   {
      case '#':
         return jjMoveStringLiteralDfa1_0(0x8L);
      case '$':
         return jjMoveStringLiteralDfa1_0(0x4L);
      case '\': // should be '\\'
         return jjStartNfaWithStates_0(0, 4, 2);
      default :
         return jjMoveNfa_0(7, 0);
   }
}
```

This is the offending grammar section from JS341 (although I'm not sure its the grammar itself) that's causing the problem:

```
<DEFAULT> TOKEN :
{
< LITERAL_EXPRESSION:
((~["\\", "$", "#"])
| ("\\" ("\\" | "$" | "#"))
| ("$" ~["{", "$"])
| ("#" ~["{", "#"])
)+
| "$"
| "#"
>
|
< START_DYNAMIC_EXPRESSION: "${" > {stack.push(DEFAULT);}:
IN_EXPRESSION
|
< START_DEFERRED_EXPRESSION: "#{" > {stack.push(DEFAULT);}:
IN_EXPRESSION
}
<DEFAULT> SKIP : { "\\" }
```

I played around with the options (JAVA_UNICODE_ESCAPE, UNICODE_INPUT) and grammar. But without result.

Question: how do I make javacc generate valid Java switch statement, i.e., with `'\\'` instead of `'\'`?

Comment: There's already a comment with what the value should be, what's the question you have?

Comment: I suppose you'll have to show your grammar.

Comment: I'll update the question with the offending grammar section.. And indeed, I would expect a `'\\'`

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error using JavaCC 5.0, 6.0, or 6.1.  What JavaCC version are you using?  And could you post a minimal self-contained example?

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell it took me a while to figure out, but I'm not using JavaCC itself but a fork: `parser-generator-cc` which is called by `ph-javacc-maven-plugin`. I'm new with parser generators, so these are my first small steps. Point is: I want to use an AST of the EL language to generate code in stead of using reflection. It will take me a while to trim back the JSR341 javaCC grammar to a small self-contained-example. In the mean time, I tried JavaCC itself as well. The above problem does not appear. However, I miss some methods now in the generated AST.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the fork.  I'd suggest reporting the bug to the maintainers.  It is also possible that the bug is in later versions of JavaCC. I'll have to look into that.  I think you can add methods to the generated AST classes without them being overwritten.

Comment: [Issue written](https://github.com/phax/ParserGeneratorCC/issues/20). Thanks for your help. I'll checkout overriding the methods.

Comment: This is a bug in pgcc 1.0.2 - it will be fixed in 1.1.0. The respective fix is already in the code base. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @PhilipHelger thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The observed behaviour is an issue and will be solved in `parser-generator-cc` 1.1.0.